# Can I disable an Android app to read write some folders in SD card? (CLOSED)

Tags: sd-card, file-management, file-permissions

So many Chinese Android apps always creates garbage in SD card, like there is their's home. Some apps auto downloads **binding apps** to SD card, when I deleted them, they come up next time! So is there any idea to prevent this? This drives my **crazy**!

Comment: The apps will probably crash or fail to work if they can't read or write data.  I think the answer is to uninstall the apps that do things you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted you can freeze them by using SD Maid or Titanium Backup OR you can use a 'Grant Permission' app to limit their permissions (freezing them is the best option IMO).
I have tried this myself on my Huawei phone and freezes all the bloatware (Chinese apps).

EDITED:
Use a permission fix app and remove the SD card reading/writing permission.

Second Update:
The app let you FIX permission for an individual app as well as all apps installed.

Comment: No no no, I need to use this app, I dont wanna freeze it!

Comment: I'm not wanting to prevent the rw on SD card, that will disable all apps to rw it. What I want is disable some apps to rw some folders or files, got it?

Answer (score 0):

For all apps I have this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86671/how-to-stop-android-from-creating-files-and-folders-on-the-sd-card/194094#194094), but if you want it for a specific app since Android 6.0 Marshmellow the is a way to [control app permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en)!

[image]

There is also the option for turning on/ off the app permissions for the device storage. If you disable that, then the app always ask you before writing/ reading on the external sd-card. Notice that also the internal storage isn't accssesable for the choiced app.